# Is there a way to append the data from a sqlalchemy query to a pandas data frame within a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm currently pulling data from a sqlalchemy query within a for loop iterating through different device id's/accon_time pairs as variables

The idea is to pull data for one device/time pair at a time and append it to a pandas data frame for later processing

The reason for this is pulling the data in bulk or even in small batches sets off a high IOPS alert for our database

At first I tried just using df.append() within the loop however I got a type error from the query object.

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "class 
>   sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query"; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

I then decided to try to convert the query object into a series and then convert the series into a data frame:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    dev_id = (df.iloc[i]['dev_id'])
    accon_time = (df.iloc[i]['accon_time'])
    new_session = Session()
    gps_qry = new_session.query(GPS).filter(GPS.dev_id == dev_id).filter(GPS.accon_time == accon_time). \
        filter(GPS.tm_time.between(20190620145813, 20190620151400))
    gps_qry = [repr(x) for x in gps_qry]
    ser_2 = pd.Series(data=gps_qry)
    #This part here is to split the comma seperated values in the series into 3 seperate columns:
    df_2 = ser_2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([val.split('=')[1] for val in x[1:-1].split(',')]))
    df_2 = df_2.append(gps_qry, ignore_index=True)
    df_2.columns = ['dev_id', 'accon_time', 'tm_time']


print(df_2)
```

I expected something like this:

```
     dev_id  accon_time  tm_time
0     'A'    'B'          'C'
1     'D'    'E'          'F'
2     'G'    'H'          'I'
```

But instead this was the result:

```
     dev_id       accon_time  tm_time
0     'A'           'B'          'C'
1     'D,E,F...'    NaN          NaN
```

I'm not too sure what's going on but this is the closest I've gotten to solving this issue as every other method raised a type error

Comment: `pandas` has `pd.read_sql()` , `pd.read_sql_query()` to read directly from database.

Comment: Use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It should help you see problem.

Comment: why do you use `repr()` ?  it is weird method to convert something. You could try `gps_qry = list(gps_qry)` or directly `ser_2 = pd.Series(data=list(gps_qry))` and maybe you will no need to `df.apply()`

Comment: @furas I've actual tried using pd.read_sql() and pd.read_sql_query() previously but always got this error message "Not an executable object"

Comment: @furas using repr() resolves an error I was getting previously saying that my data table is not subscriptable. Using list() actually raises the same error

Comment: but `repr()` converts object to string which you have to converted to object again. It is waste of time.

Comment: @furas I just attempted using your method and it does work well. However, it doesn't solve my original issue. When I append the series to itself, I only get two rows with the same exact values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I get the entire picture of your challenge, but you can use a combination of `sqlalchemy` with `pandas` by accessing the raw query that you are building with the ORM and pass it to `read_sql` as suggested by @furas. This way you can keep using the ORM for query creation.

For example:

```py
gps_qry = new_session.query(GPS).filter(GPS.dev_id == dev_id).filter(GPS.accon_time == accon_time). \
        filter(GPS.tm_time.between(20190620145813, 20190620151400))

gps_df = pd.read_sql(gps_qry.statement, con=db.engine)

## or

gps_df = pd.read_sql(str(gps_qry), con=db.engine)
```

Or using in the loop:

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):
    dev_id = (df.iloc[i]['dev_id'])
    accon_time = int((df.iloc[i]['accon_time'])) ##updated to use python int.
    new_session = Session()
    gps_qry = new_session.query(GPS).filter(GPS.dev_id == dev_id).filter(GPS.accon_time == accon_time). \
        filter(GPS.tm_time.between(20190620145813, 20190620151400))

    ### append in each loop
    gps_df = pd.read_sql(str(gps_qry), con=db.engine)
    df_2 = pd.concat([df_2, gps_df], axis=0, sort=False, ignore_index=True)


print(df_2)
```

Comment: You can still use your `.append` or even `pd.concat` with the `gps_df` for each iteration of your loop.

Comment: using either .append or pd.concat raises this error "Python value of type numpy.int64 not supported."

Comment: Have you tried transforming your `dev_id` to `int` ? I updated the answer to consider that, as some databases won't accept numpy/pandas integer types. Also, what is the format of `accon_time`? If integer, I would also use the same approach.

Comment: accon_time is an integer, but the ID values for dev_id are actually strings since they're a combination of letters and numbers

Comment: That is probably where the error is happening. Try to use `int((df.iloc[i]['accon_time']))) to transform it to a python int as opposed to numpy.int64. I updated the answer.

Comment: yep that was the issue. Awesome! thank you so much for both the fix and showing me how to actually use pd.read_sql()